# Gitlab 500 page after upgrading a gitlab setup with two-factor login

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-compose, http-status-code-500

Back in the day I used normal docker containers `sameersbn/gitlab:8.7.3` , `sameersbn/postgresql:9.4-21` and `sameersbn/redis:latest`.

I had only one secret `GITLAB_SECRETS_DB_KEY_BASE` that was probably used for my two-factor login.

I decided to use docker-compose approach and copied there yml file and used the same `DB_KEY_BASE` but filled in something difference in the other secrets.

```
GITLAB_SECRETS_DB_KEY_BASE=long-and-random-alphanumeric-string
GITLAB_SECRETS_SECRET_KEY_BASE=long-and-random-alphanumeric-string
GITLAB_SECRETS_OTP_KEY_BASE=long-and-random-alphanumeric-string
```

I slowly docker up/down my way up in higher versions.
Everything was working fine, maybe I got lucky because there was a browser session still active?
Because after my upgrade to gitlab 9.1.0 I'm getting a page 500 after I fill in the two-factor code.
Even the recovery codes don't work.

Did I break everything by filling in a different secret in `GITLAB_SECRETS_OTP_KEY_BASE`?

Comment: Just in case, would https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/30780#note_27281413 help?

Comment: Could be related, but I have not gitlab-ctl in this container yet

Comment: OK, it was just a test to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Also not possible to downgrade. Any idea how I can rerun the migrations?

Comment: If you have committed your container before migration, you could take that image as base image to retry your migration. (coupled with a copy of your database before migration)

Comment: I sadly have not a backup of the database

Comment: Do you have to put quotes around the secrets in the docker-compose file?

Comment: Looking at https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-1, no.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out I had a Daily backup. I'm back to Gitlab v9.0.5 but stil no luck. I tried to rebuild authorization keys and perform a rake db:migrate. I keep seeing: Missing Rails.application.secrets.jws_private_key for production environment. The secret will be generated and stored in config/secrets.yml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this hard to find issue

I took the value out of `/home/git/data/.secret` which is a leftover from older gitlabs and past it in my docker-compose variables `GITLAB_SECRETS_OTP_KEY_BASE` and `GITLAB_SECRETS_SECRET_KEY_BASE`

And everything works fine again :)